# when I use matlab command , matlab does not open rather it shows this error

Tags: matlab, shared-library

When I use the `matlab` command, matlab does not open but it shows this error:

[image]

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: It would be better, so copy the error message from the terminal (ctrl+shift+c) and paste it into the body of your question.

Answer (score 1):

there is an answer to probably the same question on another forum.

I will report it for clarity and if someone passes through **this** question:

To resolve this problem, open a Terminal window and use the commands below depending on your OS architecture:

**For 64-bit Ubuntu:**

```
sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /lib64/libc.so.6
```

**For 32-bit Ubuntu:**

```
sudo ln -s /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /lib/libc.so.6
```

**For using the Student Version on 64-bit:**

```
sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /lib
```

Afterwards try starting MATLAB again.

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: This does not work